# C++ copy constructor, with pointers

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

When we define the copy constructor, is it required that we clear the contents of the object we are writing over? I am implementing a binary search tree, and wondering if I wouldn't have a memory leak unless I clean it up when implementing the copy constructor and the assignment operator.

Comment: Clear what? It hasn't been constructed yet, there isn't anything to clear.

Comment: Unclear what you asking. Just ensure any allocation is paired with exactly one deallocation (new/delete, new[]/delete[], malloc/free, ...)

Comment: If you are defining a copy constructor then there is nothing to clean as you are building from scratch.

Comment: What object you are writing over? Constructors are called on object creation.

Comment: Are you confusing copy constructor with assingment operator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When we define the copy constructor, is it required that we clear the contents of the object we are writing over?

At time of construction there's no content that needs to be overwritten. Just make sure you're doing all of the copies of member variables in the constructor member initializer list, rather than doing in the constructor's body.

Otherwise the compiler would generate default initialization for members, and then there could be something allocated, that actually needs to be cleared and overwritten (or *deep copied*).

Especially if you're dealing *with pointers* as you claim to do.

Best you should follow [The Rule of Three (Five)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) to ensure everything is done consistently.

Comment: Upvoting for actually making sense of the seemingly senseless question by bringing members into the picture.

Comment: @SergeyA: I shall try not to take that personally.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, how did you come into picture? And what happened to the red herring comment I was going to address?

Comment: @SergeyA: I came into the picture because you didn't want to also upvote my answer :(

Comment: That comment was a red herring so I deleted it ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There are differences for implementations in the member initializer list vs copying in the constructors body? Don't see you mentioned that, neither the _red herrings_ so much? But have an upvote, so what :-P ...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I didn't expect someone with almost 200K rep to even think about reputation :) But I see no reason not to upvote it.

Comment: @SergeyA: I didn't say anything about reputation!

Comment: @SergeyA It's more about accepting _correctness_ ... I don't care about the rep so much.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, πάντα ῥεῖ - OK. I am still not clear what is considered a good answer here (for example, I was often downvoted for answers which I believe to be similar to LRiOs with comments - *useless* or *this should be a comment*.

Comment: @SergeyA: People are silly

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit _"People are silly"_ I've been prooving this soo many times ;-) ...

Answer (score 4):

If a copy constructor is running, there is no "object we are writing over". You are creating ("constructing") a new object, from scratch, but copying data from some other object to populate its initial state.

For an assignment operator, yes this is definitely a consideration and you need to be sure to avoid leaks. Though, if you employ RAII so you don't have any manual memory management, then you have nothing to worry about. (Beyond that, I don't understand how pointers come into it.)

Answer (score 1):

As the others have stated, using the copy constructor will create a new object.
What you have to consider, tho:
If your original object is the owner of some other data e.g. `foo*` allocated with `new` or a `shared_ptr`, copying the object will simply copy the pointer and its adress.
You will not actually copy the owned data.
In case of a raw `foo*` and a `delete foo` in your destructor, the second object being destroyed will try to delete removed memory.